# Using bearer authorization with PostMan

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, postman

I am looking for an easy way to add bearer tokens to PostMan. I have imported my API into PostMan from a swagger definition, and am wondering if authorization can be added automatically to all requests in some easy way, such that I do not have to change the Authorization header for each endpoint whenever the token changes.

I am currently requesting a token at `/token` for my API by sending an `x-www-form-urlencoded` request containing the parameters `username`, `password` and `grant_type` with a `password` value.

The returned `access_token` is then appended to the Authorization header in the format `"Bearer token-received-from-token-endpoint"` for each request to the API.

The backend is implemented with AspNet Identity Framework and AspNet Web API 2.

Comment: best answer using Environments and Variables here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785592/bearer-token-in-postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good approach here is [chaining request](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/)

When you get a token, assign it to an environment variable and use that variable in your subsequent requests. 
This way you will have a fresh token every time and your other requests can use that on runtime

Comment: Exactly what I need. Though I wish that the token could be added automatically for all subsequent requests.