# Bearer token in postman

Tags: postman

I want to set a **`Bearer Token`** in postman

For some reason my Postman doesn't have the `Bearer Token` option in the Auth dropdown

What can I do in Postman to show that option? Any ideas where I can find it? Regards.

Comment: You need to install the latest version. I had the same issue in 5.3 and updated to the latest 6.3 and fix my problem.

Comment: Or  you are using google chrome extension version, it is deprecated... New features are not available in it.

Comment: You can even change the word Bearer, in cases where you want to use `Token token` - https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4727#issuecomment-775977045

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I'm not sure if those 2 images are from the same Postman application or not but the Bearer Token feature only came in on version 5.3.0.

You can just manually add an `Authorization` Request Header with a `Bearer <my_token>` value.

This is *just* a dummy value for demo purposes - The actual value should be `Bearer + your token value`.

[image: Auth Header]

That should work without the need to use that option from the drop down list. This would only just replicate automatically, what you would be doing manually anyway.

Comment: But my postman extension version is `5.5.4`, it is still does not have `Bearer Token` type, is that version is different for it's browser Extension or Desktop app

Comment: The browser extension is now deprecated. The desktop app is what you would need to be using and this is currently at 7.16.0 so many versions ahead the old extension.

Answer (score 47):

*I am using Postman v7.0.9.*

Add accessToken variable to postman environmental variable.

[image]

Then use Tests tab to write javascript.

[image]

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
let token = jsonData.accessToken;
pm.environment.set('accessToken', token);
```

If you are usign the current version "Bearer Token" type is under Authorization tab.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Cigi!! For everyone else, this is full answer! This will parse the 'token' field from the JSON response and update the environmental variable automatically.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You have a some options to add authorization type:

1) Go headers tap and add => key: Authorization value:Bearer

2) Create collection > select authorization

3) click code and add headers

[image]

```
headers:
{
  'Postman-Token': '55..',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbG...'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> Add manually in Header, Key as Authorization and Value as Bearer + space then your token like the below snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

#### Feb, 2021 - Following worked for me

From the type, choose 'Bearer Token'.

Enter Token in the field as shown below in screenshot:

[image]

Comment: yeah, worked! It would be nice if you explain it bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Postman with Chrome or Chrome extension of Postman, It doesn't have more authorization options.

So Just [download the new postman app](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), it has more features and you will get the Bearer Token option too.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your auth request url is
../authentication/v1/login
and it responses with some json as:

```
},
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1N.....
```

and you want to send the token to your server
.../service/hello request

Steps:

1. in the /public/authentication/v1/login
   in 'Tests' folder put:

   let jsonData = pm.response.json();

   let token = jsonData.token;

   pm.environment.set('myToken', token);
2. in ../service/hello
   in the 'Authentication' folder
   select 'Bearer Token'
   and in 'Token' field put {{myToken}}

TEST it

1. send POST ../authentication/v1/login (usin the SEND button)
2. check the 'Environment quick look'
   examine 'myToken' field value
3. in ../service/hello request
   hover above {{myToken}} - you will see the current value

The 'myToken' will be sent automatically with your server call.

by yl.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem a long time ago. And I solved this problem by installing the Desktop version and again login with Google account. After that Bearer Token visible in postman!

In my case, I used Windows 8.1 and 64 bit.

[here](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) you can get the desktop version