# Error: The action you requested is not allowed. My API is blocked by filters when the HTTP request method is "POST" in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am building a Web App along with API for Android using CI4.

For the Web App, I have a filter to check whether the user already logged in with some exceptions, one of them is to ignore the filter if the URL consists **api/*** (The url for API is http://localip/api/)

The API is working fine if the request method is GET. I can get the data from API. But when I tried to insert a data to database using POST method, it redirects me to login page (I'm using Postman to test the API)

How do I fix this?

What I have tried so far was adding login filter alias to

```
public $methods = [
        'post' => ['csrf', 'loginfilter']
    ]; But still not working
```

Here is the full code

**Filters.php**

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use App\Filters\CorsFilter;
use App\Filters\LoginFilter;
use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\InvalidChars;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\SecureHeaders;

class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * Configures aliases for Filter classes to
     * make reading things nicer and simpler.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $aliases = [
        'loginfilter' => LoginFilter::class,
        'cors' => CorsFilter::class
    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that are always
     * applied before and after every request.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            // 'honeypot',
            'csrf',
            'loginfilter' => ['except' => ['/', '/login', 'api/*']],
            'cors'
            // 'invalidchars',
        ],
        'after' => [
            'toolbar',
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'secureheaders',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that works on a
     * particular HTTP method (GET, POST, etc.).
     *
     * Example:
     * 'post' => ['csrf', 'throttle']
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $methods = [
        'post' => ['csrf','loginfilter]
    ];

    /**
     * List of filter aliases that should run on any
     * before or after URI patterns.
     *
     * Example:
     * 'isLoggedIn' => ['before' => ['account/*', 'profiles/*']]
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $filters = [];
}
```

**LoginFilter.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

class LoginFilter implements FilterInterface
{

    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        $session = session();
        if (!$session->has('user_id')) {
            return redirect()->to(base_url() . '/');
        }
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
    }
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
$routes->resource("api/role", ['controller' => 'apis\MasterDataRoleApi']);
```

**MasterDataRoleApi.php (Controller)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\apis;

use App\Models\GeneralModels;
use App\Models\RoleModel;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;

class MasterDataRoleApi extends ResourceController
{
    use ResponseTrait;
    protected $model;
    protected $generalModel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new RoleModel();
        $this->generalModel = new GeneralModels();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $role= $this->request->getVar('role');
        $data = $this->model->getRoleApi($role);
        return $this->respond($data, 200);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $roleName = $this->request->getPost('role_name');
        $supervisor = $this->request->getPost('supervisor');
        $userId = $this->request->getVar("userId");
        helper('idgenerator');
        $maxCode = $this->generalModel->getMaxData('tmrole', 'role_id');
        $generatedId = idGenerator($maxCode[0]['role_id'], 4, 3, "JAB-");

        $this->model->insertTmRole($generatedId, $roleName, $userId, $userId);
       

        $data = array();

        $dataArr = array(
            "response" => "Success",
            "response_details" => "Saved Successfully"
        );

        $data[] =  $dataArr;

        return $this->respondCreated($data, 201);
    }
}
```

Image below shows Json returned when request method is GET https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZKPd.png

Image below shows login page returned when request method is POST
https://i.stack.imgur.com/11R0z.png

Thank you in advance.

Comment: hang on, the `loginfilter` job is to redirect non-logged in user, right? on `$global` you've set `loginfilter` to exclude `api/*` ,correct? now, i do wonder, why on earth `loginfilter` has to run on `$methods->post`? wont that make every post fails if you're not logged in?

Comment: Even if loginfilters is not included in $methods->post, it still doesn't work. By default, $methods->post only contain csrf and yet the API doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### PART A: CSRF

##### Explanation 1:

> Image below shows Json returned when request method is GET
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZKPd.png

Your API `GET` requests work just fine because they're **not** protected.

[Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)

> The CSRF Protection is only available for
> `POST`/`PUT`/`PATCH`/`DELETE` requests. Requests for other methods are
> not protected.

##### Explanation 2:

> Image below shows login page returned when request method is POST
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/11R0z.png

**Error**

```sh
The action you requested is not allowed.
```

That error comes from **[system/Security/Security.php::verify()](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/cb4d68b60ded446374f73a78cf5f42de7ecf880a/system/Security/Security.php#L271)**

[`throw SecurityException::forDisallowedAction();`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/cb4d68b60ded446374f73a78cf5f42de7ecf880a/system/Security/Security.php#L286)

You normally receive this error in 2 scenarios:

1. When you forgot to submit the CSRF token along with your request (**POST/PUT/etc.**).
2. When the CSRF token submitted along with your HTML form/request body **doesn't** match the one that exists in the CSRF cookie.

[After having turned on the CSRF filter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#enable-csrf-protection), when you make an HTTP request and are missing a CSRF cookie, one is auto-generated for you and sent in the HTTP `Set-Cookie: '...'` response header.

In case you're using the **default** Cookie-based CSRF Protection, with any further (**POST/PUT/etc.**) requests made, you will be expected to submit a **matching** CSRF token along with your request.

[Double Submit Cookie](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie)

> This technique is easy to implement and is stateless. In this
> technique, we send a random value in both a cookie and as a request
> parameter, with the server verifying if the cookie value and request
> value match. When a user visits (even before authenticating to prevent
> login CSRF), the site should generate a (cryptographically strong)
> pseudorandom value and set it as a cookie on the user's machine
> separate from the session identifier. The site then requires that
> every transaction request include this pseudorandom value as a hidden
> form value (or other request parameter/header). If both of them match
> at server side, the server accepts it as legitimate request and if
> they don't, it would reject the request.

##### CSRF Solution:

To pass the *Double Submit Cookie* test, every time you make a (**POST/PUT/etc.**) request, you will need to submit a CSRF cookie and a request parameter/header having a **matching** CSRF token. I.e:

**Requirement 1:** `Cookie: csrf_cookie_name=ccd8facfa8229bdba5e0160c108d1a02;` HTTP request header.

**Requirement 2:**

[The Order of Token Sent by Users](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#the-order-of-token-sent-by-users)

The order of checking the availability of the CSRF token is as follows:

1. `$_POST` array (I.e: `<input type="hidden" name="<?= csrf_token() ?>" value="<?= csrf_hash() ?>" />`).
2. HTTP header (I.e: `X-CSRF-TOKEN: ccd8facfa8229bdba5e0160c108d1a02`).
3. `php://input` (JSON request) - bear in mind that this approach is the slowest one since we have to decode JSON and then re-encode it. (I.e: `{"csrf_cookie_name": "ccd8facfa8229bdba5e0160c108d1a02"}`)

*Requirement 1* is normally auto-fulfilled by the browser if that's where you're initiating the request from. Nonetheless, you can manually fulfil it. I.e: In your PHP main view template, you can use Ajax:

```php
<script>
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 
                "<?php echo csrf_header();?>": "<?php echo csrf_hash();?>",

                "Cookie": "<?php echo csrf_token();?>"="<?php echo csrf_hash();?>"; "<?php echo session_name();?>":"<?php echo session_id();?>"
             }
        });

<script>
```

---

Below are my personal `.env` file configurations that worked for me.

Change *myapp.local* to your application's domain.

`.env` file.

```sh
app.baseURL = 'http://myapp.local'
app.sessionExpiration = 86400

cookie.domain = '.myapp.local'
cookie.httponly = false

security.expires = 86400
security.regenerate = false
```

The rest of the `.env` file configurations related to *SECURITY/CSRF, COOKIE, APP/SESSION* were maintained in their default setting.

As I conclude the CSRF section, if you still have issues, install & configure [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/install), add break points inside this method **[system/Security/Security.php::verify()](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/cb4d68b60ded446374f73a78cf5f42de7ecf880a/system/Security/Security.php#L271)** and confirm if your HTTP request is passing the conditions in there. Make sure your Xdebug configurations are similar to: (`xdebug.log_level = 0 | xdebug.mode = debug,develop | xdebug.start_with_request = yes | xdebug.client_port = 9004 | xdebug.client_host = "localhost" | xdebug.trace_output_name = "trace.%c.%t-%s.%H_%R" | xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s.%H_%R" | xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp" | xdebug.show_local_vars = 9`)

#### PART B: [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) OR [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/)

This section covers setting up your REST API client application tool to be able to test your project's end-points.

**HTTP Request Header Requirements:**

1. `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`
2. `X-CSRF-TOKEN: 62b04a891414ef789bee7108f94ad97a`
3. `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
4. `Accept: */*`
5. `Cookie: csrf_cookie_name=62b04a891414ef789bee7108f94ad97a; ci_session=4ji7amn186ckbo0gutdoe3ai6ufumk4e`
6. `User-Agent: insomnia/2022.1.1`
7. `Host: myapp.local`

*The above headers are **mandatory**. You may add other HTTP request headers after the ones listed above.*

The `User-Agent` can vary depending on if you are using one tool or another (I.e Insomnia or Postman).

The `Host` can vary as well, depending on how you set up your application's base URL.

The `Content-Type` can vary, depending on the kind of data you're submitting to the server. (I.e. HTML FORM -> `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and JSON -> `application/json`).

As for the `Cookie` header, you may need to attach the `ci_session` (session_id) cookie if in case your endpoint is behind an Authentication system or Login filter. Of course, this may **not** be necessary if your API uses a different Auth mechanism (i.e: using [Bearer/Access tokens](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#bearer-token) with an extra [`Authorization: Bearer xxx_my_bearer_token_here` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785592/bearer-token-in-postman)).
In addition, you may need to attach a `csrf_cookie_name` cookie as shown above if your [application has enabled the `csrf` filter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#enable-csrf-protection). In this case, you may want to create a dedicated `GET` API route endpoint specifically to allow you receive a `csrf` cookie name and value (hash). Alternatively, if you're too lazy to set up a dedicated endpoint for sending out CSRF tokens and you already have the web app running, open your browser's console while logging in/navigating through your app, in the **Application TAB -> Cookies -> your domain**, you should be able to see and utilize these cookies in Postman / Insomnia.

[image]

The `X-CSRF-TOKEN` HTTP request header value should be the **same** as the `csrf_cookie_name` cookie value.

**HTTP Request Call Requirements:**

I.e:

`POST http://myapp.local/api/companies`

*Request Body. Don't forget to add the `csrf_cookie_name` token as part of the request body.*

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| company_name | Tesla, Inc. |
| csrf_cookie_name | 62b04a891414ef789bee7108f94ad97a |

---

**As I conclude with *PART B:***

| Important items | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `ci_session` cookie ***or*** an `Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx` HTTP request header. | Allows you to authenticate with your application/project ***only*** for Auth protected API endpoints. In your particular case, I believe your `loginfilter` is working with a `ci_session` cookie and the cookie is expected to be sent along with every request with the help of the `Cookie` HTTP request header. |
| `csrf_cookie_name` cookie ***and*** (a `X-CSRF-TOKEN` HTTP request header ***or*** CSRF token request parameter). | The CSRF cookie ***and*** (`X-CSRF-TOKEN` HTTP request header ***or*** CSRF token request parameter) values **MUST** match. This is a requirement if [you've turned on the `csrf` filter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#enable-csrf-protection). |

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see is, you have loginfilter as a fallback for every POST method. That might be the culprit over there.

That being said, here is an alternate solution. You could group the routes in routes.php and apply `loginfilter` to those routes. Additionally you can nest them and partition them as you want.

Example :

```
$routes->group(
    'api',
    ['filter' => 'loginfilter'],
    function ($routes) {
        $routes->resource("role", ['controller' => 'apis\MasterDataRoleApi']);
    }
);
```

You can remove the global filters while using this method.